# How can I replace an element in AngularDart >= 1.0

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

Answer seems easy - but it isn't, at least not for me.

Here is a complete sample on GitHub: https://github.com/MikeMitterer/Angular.Accordion 
Transpiled to JS: (working sample) http://www.mikemitterer.at/fileadmin/sourcesamples/accordion/ 
The code-part I'm talking about: http://goo.gl/BlihdM

What I want is taking a html-snippet, in this case "accordion-toolbar" and move it to another place in DOM.

```
<accordion-group heading="With Toolbar" >
    <accordion-toolbar>
        Hallo Toolbar
    </accordion-toolbar>
    This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
</accordion-group>
```

Result:

[image]

Here comes the problem:

```
@Component(selector: 'accordion-toolbar')
class AccordionToolbarComponent {

    AccordionToolbarComponent(final html.Element element,final AccordionGroupComponent group) {
        // worked pre Angular 1.0
        //element.remove();
        //group.toolbar = element;

        // Hack??? (was necessary for Decorator - but ist obsolete now for Component)
        // element.style.display = "none";
        group.toolbar = element.innerHtml;
    }
}
```

`element.remove();` worked for pre 1.0 but now if you remove the element it's somehow restored by Angular. Now I set the display-style to none and create a new Element - but there must be a better way...

Snippet shows how one accordion-li is defined:
**[ Update ]** 
changed the Template from `<content-append>...</content-append>` to `<span ng-bind-html="toolbar"></span>`

```html
<li class="panel panel-default accordion">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-minus-square': isOpen, 'fa-plus-square': !isOpen}" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen"></i>
            <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen">
                <span ng-bind-html="header"></span>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="accordion-toolbar pull-right" ng-if="toolbar != null">
            <span ng-bind-html="toolbar"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse accordion collapse" collapse="!isOpen">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <content></content>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**[ Update II ]]**
I'm still not sure if hiding the base element is just an ugly hack but the main problem is that bindings don't work in ng-bind-html.

I found Günters sample: http://goo.gl/GVOHPA but it seems not to work anymore.

**[ Update III ]]**
One step further. I borrowed some code from Angular-NgInclude.

```dart
@Decorator(selector: 'my-bind-html')
class MyBindHtmlComponent {
    final _logger = new Logger('webapp_base_ui_angular.mm_uia_accordion.MyBindHtmlDirective');

    final html.Element element;
    final ViewFactoryCache viewFactoryCache;
    final DirectiveInjector directiveInjector;
    final DirectiveMap directives;

    // Here I can use RootScope or Scope 
    final RootScope scope;

    View _view;
    Scope _childScope;

    MyBindHtmlComponent(this.element, this.scope, this.viewFactoryCache, this.directiveInjector, this.directives);

    @NgOneWay('node')
    set node(value) {

        _cleanUp();

        if (value != null && value != '') {
            _updateContent(viewFactoryCache.fromHtml(value, directives));
        }
    }

    _cleanUp() {
        if (_view == null) return;
        _view.nodes.forEach((node) => node.remove);
        _childScope.destroy();
        _childScope = null;
        element.innerHtml = '';
        _view = null;
    }

    _updateContent(final ViewFactory viewFactory) {
        // create a new scope
        _childScope = scope.createProtoChild();
        _view = viewFactory(_childScope, directiveInjector);
        _view.nodes.forEach((node) => element.append(node));
    }
}
```

Template in accordion_group:

```html
<li class="panel panel-default accordion">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-minus-square': isOpen, 'fa-plus-square': !isOpen}" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen"></i>
            <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen">
                <my-bind-html node="header"></my-bind-html>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="accordion-toolbar pull-right" ng-if="toolbar != null">
            <my-bind-html node="toolbar"></my-bind-html>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse accordion collapse" collapse="!isOpen">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <content></content>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

It's not bad - it's almost working. The final problem now is which Scope to use. If I use Scope then it only gets/binds the vars defined in accordion-group. If I use RootScope it gets the vars defined in AppController.

```html
<accordion-group ng-repeat="name in names" heading="Dynamic <strong>{{name}}</strong> {{title}}">
    <accordion-toolbar>
        <a class="toolbar" href="#">Hallo {{name}} + Title: {{title}}</a>
    </accordion-toolbar>
    Ich bin Blindtext. Von Geburt an. Es hat lange gedauert, bis ich begriffen habe, was es
    bedeutet,
    ein blinder Text zu sein: Man macht keinen Sinn. Man wirkt hier und da aus dem Zusammenhang
    gerissen.
</accordion-group>
```

If I use RootScope it can't find *name*.
I get

```
Class 'AccordionGroupComponent' has no instance getter 'name'.
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'name'
Receiver: Instance of 'AccordionGroupComponent'
Arguments: []
```

Any hints?